# ExtJS 4.0.7: Nested grids/RowExpander

Tags: extjs, listeners

I have a couple of questions regarding nested grids in Ext JS 4.0.7:

1. I have a nested grid that consists of a RowExpander which is replaced with a newly loaded grid based on "parent_id" that is sent through "prototype.js" to PHP and then PHP returns an answer from the database. It is working fine, but the nested grid does not fire on the `expandbody` as the above does. What is the selector I have to use to access all "gridview"s inside the current gridview? (I have tried `#mainGrid gridview`, but without success)
2. Is there a way to set the width of the RowExpanding column? Because it's taking a lot of space at the moment.
3. Is there a way to set the height of the row that expands?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The selector to use was simply just "gridview" in the controller.
2. The width of the rowexpanding column had to do with the gridpanel's layout settings. Sat it to "hbox" and it solved itself.
3. The height was set by the nested grid's height.